# How do I add the auto increment values with java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, prepared-statement

I created a table in Mysql using

```
Create table 
(
 id int auto_increment,
 us varchar(100),
 ps varchar(1000)
);
```

And used java for adding values thru my GUI application:

I used the following method to add values into my database:

```
public static void Mysql(String u, String p) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        String hashpass=passhash(p);//throws declaration for this statement
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bs","root","root");   
            String query = " insert into login (id,us,ps)"
                    + " values (?,?, ?)";  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from login"); 
            int id=0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                id= rs.getInt(1);
            }
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setInt(1, id++); //I don't want this method because id is auto increment
            preparedStmt.setString(2,u);
            preparedStmt.setString(3,hashpass);
            preparedStmt.execute();
            con.close();  
            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
              
    }
```

> ***Everything works fine***

But the id is the auto_increment and I don't need to add value to id while adding other column values.

I can't add like that while adding thru java like only adding us, ps columns and the id will be automatically incremented.

> **Are there any methods to add data without passing the parameters?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the column `id` from the sql statement:

```
String query = "insert into login (us, ps) values (?, ?)";
```

and don't set any value for it in the prepared statement, so remove this line:

```
preparedStmt.setInt(1, id++);
```

The column `id` is `auto_inrement` so its value will be set by MySql.
Of course change the indices of the other lines to 1 and 2:

```
preparedStmt.setString(1,u);
preparedStmt.setString(2,hashpass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might insert data without ID as it will be auto-generated from SQL

```java
public static void Mysql(String u,String p) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    String hashpass=passhash(p);
    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bs","root","root");   
        String query = " insert into login (us,ps) values (?, ?)"; // CHECK HERE  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from login"); 
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1,u);
        preparedStmt.setString(2,hashpass);
        preparedStmt.execute();
        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);}           
    }
}
```